# App launches slowly on iPhone 4/4s at first launch

Tags: ios, iphone, splash-screen, launching-application

I am observing a wierd issue on iPhone 4/4S and sometimes iPhone 5/5S too. App launch time (at splash screen) is more than usual. I have compared and after installing (first fresh install) it takes about 7-10 sec at the launch image. That is too much and I am worried about my app rejection. (even if not rejection than its a bad user experience for sure). 
On iPhone 6/6s it is fine. From the second launch it takes normal acceptable time of 3-4 sec.

Now the funny part is when I delete the app and reinstall it loads relatively faster like 3-4 sec. Also from 2nd launch the app launches in about the same time or lesser.

Now to reproduce I delete the app and installs again after 3-4 hrs it gives the same issue of taking longer time to launch for the first launch.

I don’t know if system caches the launch image until some period of time even after deleting the app. (As it launches faster if delete the app and reinstalls quickly).

Also how to quickly launch the app? Any tips? I am using image xcassets and iOS version supported is iOS 7 and above. 
Does it make difference if launch image is more than 1 mb and should I use jpg to reduce size?

Note:
It's taking time at launch image itself. I am curious to know why it's just first time launch after install. Like after killing the app and relaunching doesn't take that much time. And it's device specific only. Not seeing on iPhone 6 and above. I saw issue on iPad 2 as well.

Comment: Your concern is legitimate. Fast app launching is crucial; in fact, there's a WWDC video all about this one topic, which I suggest you watch. Meanwhile, use Instruments to figure out what's slowing you down. It's probably a threading issue, but that's just a guess. You give no specific information about what you _do_ at launch time, so no one here can help you; you have to help yourself. For example, if you gather info from the web during launch on the main thread, that is utterly wrong behavior.

Comment: Post you applicationDidFinishLaunching method. That will help to diagnose the issue

Comment: It's taking time at launch image itself. I am curious to know why it's just first time launch after install. Like after killing the app and relaunching doesn't take that much time.

Comment: "It's taking time at launch image itself" I doubt it - unless you are saying that app launch takes a long time when launched _from Xcode_. If so, that's a complete red herring and you should ignore it. Xcode itself is slow to install and launch an app, but that tells you _nothing_ about the behavior of the app in the real world. The only way to test launch time is to install on a device, quit, and then launch by tapping the icon on the device.

Comment: I am testing on device (iPhone 4S) from the hockeyapp build. It's taking time only for the first time. After I kill the app and relaunch it takes normal time (3-4 sec).

Comment: Like it's already been said, we'd have to look at your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method if you want some help.
When a user taps the icon, the OS animates the launch screen image, then executes the method `applicationDidFinishLaunching` in the `AppDelegate`, and AFTER that it removes the launch screen, so the hangup is almost definitely being caused by your implementation of said method. (Are you loading a lot of stuff from disk? Making network requests?)

Comment: If that's the case then shouldn't it be happening all the time - like killing the app and launch again at this time? (But it's not happening always.. it's just first time launch when app is installed)